# target=“_blank” is not working in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I try to show base64 source image when click this text. But it not working in chrome. tag open new tab. But href not in url.

My Html Code :

```
<div>
  <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
  <a href="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" target="_blank">Please Click here</a>
</div>
```

How to resolve that issue?

Comment: You place data-image as URI, definitlty wont work.

Comment: Top-level navigation to data URIs is prevented for security reasons.

Comment: What does a completely blank screenshot add to the question?

Comment: @Amy it shows what happens in Chrome. This link works in Firefox normally.

Comment: @VLAZ "This works in Firefox normally, but in Chrome, the URL bar is blank and I get a blank page."  Takes a lot less bandwidth and communicates more information, and can be indexed by search engines.

Comment: @Amy feel free to make an [edit] that improves the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to do that with javascript, you can try this:

```
var image = new Image();

image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

var _window = window.open('');
_window.document.write(image.outerHTML);
```

Comment: New page render completed.But browser loading not finished.Is there any option for stop loading ?

Comment: @ObethSamuel Sorry, what do you mean `loading not finished`? Is there any error? Or your image is too large that makes the browser takes a long time to load?

Comment: Sorry image was loaded.But still doesn't complete full page render.

Comment: @ObethSamuel You want to display the image in new window at center position, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can not open url data as blank. its forbidden.

may check this discussion here https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM%5B1-25%5D

Answer (score 0):

A top level data URI won't work. If it did, it would be all too easy to create malicious links.